# Sequenced page numbers on alternate pages in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am having an issue regarding the page number in the XSLT. I am taking in an XML and generating the PDF using XSLT. My requirement is to have sequenced page numbers on the alternate pages.

For Example: First page will have page number **1**, then the next page (that is the second page) will not count any page number, and then on the third page the page number will be **2** and so on.

Currently I am taking a default page number value : `<fo:page-number>`

Please help as due to variable assigning constraint in XSLT i can't build up a logic for my requirement.

Thank you.

Comment: You are probably using a loop and trying to assign different values to a `<xsl:variable>`, which won't work. But there are solutions. Please edit your question and include your code so we can suggest a possible solution. Include a sufficient example (your input XML, XSL and an example of the expected result)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using xslfo, you can create two simple-page-master templates, one for even page and other for odd page. In the page-sequence for even page, add a block with an id. Now use this id in page-number-citation.